# how to make a counter inside a loop in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on PIR sensor in order to detect the movement of human beings.  Here is below the code that currently I am using and I just need to make a counter inside the loop in order to count the # of movements. Thanks in advance!!

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.IN)    # PIR motion sensor
GPIO.setup(3, GPIO.OUT)    #LED output pin
while True:
    i=GPIO.input(11)
    if i==0:               #sensor is LOW
        print "Not Occupied",i
        GPIO.output(3, 0)  #Turn OFF LED
        time.sleep(0.1)
    elif i==1:             # sensor is HIGH
        print "Occupied",i
        GPIO.output(3, 1)  #Turn ON LED
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: If you're going to post Python code, you need to reproduce your indentation. Unindented Python code is nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

When I was starting with Raspberry Pi, I was using only `RPi.GPIO` library, but now I am using only `gpiozero` library. I think, it is more clear than `RPi.GPIO`

Here is my solution of your problem using library `gpiozero` instead of `RPi.GPIO`:

```
from gpiozero import LED, MotionSensor
from signal import pause

pir = MotionSensor(11)
led = LED(3)
motion_counter = 0

def on_motion():
    global motion_counter
    led.on()
    motion_counter += 1
    print(motion_counter)

def on_no_motion():
    led.off()

pir.when_motion = on_motion
pir.when_no_motion = on_no_motion

pause()
```

More about this great library: https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 0):

Your question is kind of confusing but here is how you would set a counter

```
counter = 0
while True:
   counter += 1
   i=GPIO.input(11)
   if i==0:                 #sensor is LOW
       print "Not Occupied",i
       GPIO.output(3, 0)  #Turn OFF LED
       time.sleep(0.1)
   elif i==1:               # sensor is HIGH
       print "Occupied",i
       GPIO.output(3, 1)  #Turn ON LED
       time.sleep(0.1)`
   print(counter)
```